# "Null pointer access: The variable bn can only be null at this location"

Tags: selenium

```
private static void browsername(String CHl) {
        String bn = null;
        if(bn.equalsIgnoreCase("CH"))
        {
         System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\axis banca\\chromedriver.exe");
         driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
    }
    }
```

While writing this method in Java, I am getting this null pointer when I am trying to use it inside "if":

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is because you initialize `bn` to `null`, and then immediately try and evaluate the value of `bn`.

Seems like you should be assigning a value to `bn` first?

To add on to my comments below, your code should probably look something like:

```
private static void browsername(String CHl) {
    String bn = CHl;
    if(bn.equalsIgnoreCase("CH")) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\axis banca\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
}
```

or:

```
private static void browsername(String CHl) {
    if(CHl.equalsIgnoreCase("CH")) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\axis banca\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that it tries to call bn.equalsIgnoreCase and bn does not have such a method, since it is null. Evaluating the value of bn would not necessarily throw an exception. if (bn == null) would be syntactically correct, for instance.

Comment: what value should i assign ,if i am simply declaring "bn" it is automatically giving me null to be used

Comment: Just from the snippet above, it seems that maybe it should be `bn = CHl`. However, as @LajosArpad has put in their answer, if this is the case, you could get rid of `bn` entirely, and just do `if(CHl.equalsIgnoreCase(CH))` instead.

Comment: thnx guys but it is not happening i am new to this so facing this  issue ,, actaully i am passing browser name to this method  //browsername("CH");: and then calling that method whihc i have mentioned above.

Comment: Yes, you're passing the browser name to the method, but you're not doing anything with it or `bn` except for setting it to `null`. So when you type `if(bn.equalsIgnoreCase("CH"))` what you're actually doing (hypothetically) is seeing if `null == "CH"` which obviously won't work, because it's `null`. So you either need to give `bn` a value, or in the line above replace `bn` with `CHl`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code chunk:

```
    String bn = null;
    if(bn.equalsIgnoreCase("CH"))
```

You initialize `bn` with `null` and then call its `equalsIgnoreCase` method. Since `bn` is `null`, it does not have an `equalsIgnoreCase` method, hence the `NullPointerException`. You might want to do this instead

```
    if(CHl.equalsIgnoreCase("CH"))
```

EDIT:

If `CHl` is the browser name, like 'Chrome', then you will need a function which converts the browser name into the two-charactered thing you are checking against.

Comment: if i use Ch1 it again asks me to initiallizze Ch1..?

Comment: @NeerajRathor because it is not CH.